# Separate login sessions for multiple subdomains in a single flask app

Tags: python, flask, session, cookies, flask-login

I have a single flask app that handles multiple subdomains
lets say we have

- `www.domain.com` for customers
- `workers.domain.com` for workers

---

I am using different blueprints for each subdomain like this

```
customers = Blueprint('customers', __name__, subdomain="www")
```

```
workers = Blueprint('workers', __name__, subdomain="workers")
```

---

and for AUTH we are using `flask-login`

I've successfully managed to setup different **REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE** for different subdomains  by setting

```
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
```

---

**what I am trying to do** is to have multiple accounts(sessions) for each email logged in to each subdomain simultaneously

for instance If I am a worker I want to log in to my worker account at `workers.domain.com` and at the same time login to my customer account at `www.domain.com`

the problem is that flask uses the same session cookie for all the subdomains meaning that if I login to the workers subdomain and in the same browser I open the customers subdomain Flask will give me the same session cookie and I will be logged in the customers subdomain with a worker account which causes a lot of other issues

[image]

---

***What I tried***

- setting [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN) to None
  and still the same session cookie is shared across all subdomains

---

**Some possible solutions that I didn't know how to implement**

- having different `SECRET_KEY` for different subdomains (or blueprints)
- reimplementing the session cookie to have the user ID encoded with the subdomain by the secret key

Any Ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the [Config Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)

> **`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`**
> The domain match rule that the session cookie will be valid for.
> If `not set (None)`, the cookie will be *valid for all subdomains of SERVER_NAME*.
> If `False`, the cookie’s domain will not be set.
> *`Default: None`*

the solution was to set

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = False
```

so that the session-cookie’s domain was not set and hence by default the browser will set it to the current exact domain (and subdomain)

which means *different sessions for different subdomains in the same flask app object*