# Prevent shared session in flask subdomains

Tags: python, flask, session, subdomain

I have a flask running at http://base1.homologation.test.

I also have another flask instance on same server running at http://base2.homologation.test

they are two different systems, operating independently.

Whenever I log in to the first one, I can check the session data referring to it in the second, causing both application and security errors.

How can I prevent the sessions from being shared between the apps, so that each one has its own?

root views.py

```
from flask import *
from . import app

app.secret_key = 'random string'

@app.route('/', subdomain='base1')
def base1():
    pass

@app.route('/', subdomain='base2')
def base2():
    pass

@app.route('/')
def hqq():
    return render_template('test.html')
```

root init.py

```
from flask import *
from .base1 import base1
from .base2 import base2

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(base1, subdomain='base1')
app.register_blueprint(base2, subdomain='base2')

import E_Commerce.views
```

PS: I am using the default session (session['']).

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69205363/separate-login-sessions-for-multiple-subdomains-in-a-single-flask-app

Comment: Thank you, this link really helped me and the problem is solved: app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN'] = False